How to make TextSpan long pressable and its container long pressable?
I am trying to implement an IM text content widget. When the widget contains a hyperlink, user can tap the link to open it directly, or long press the link to open a context menu providing further operations. User can also long press the entire message to copy the entire text.
My current problem is both the container and the text need long press event, but the text container intercepts the RichText's long press event. I cannot figure out a way to pass the long press event to the RichText.

By asking ChatGPT, I wrapped the text container with a GestureDetector which handles onLongPressStart to check if the tap lands on a hyperlink area, and I set its behavior to HitTestBehavior.translucent which should allow long press event passing to its child RichText. But it is still not working.
Below is the code.
Thanks in advance!
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
import 'package:world_street_flutter/global_ui.dart';
import 'package:world_street_flutter/pages/general/web_view_page.dart';
import 'package:world_street_flutter/utils/toast_utils.dart';

class InstantMessageTextContent extends StatefulWidget {
  final String text;
  final Function(String)? longPress;
  final Function(String)? longPressLink;

  const InstantMessageTextContent({super.key, required this.text, this.longPress, this.longPressLink});

  @override
  _InstantMessageTextContentState createState() => _InstantMessageTextContentState();
}

class _InstantMessageTextContentState extends State<InstantMessageTextContent> {
  static final urlPattern = RegExp(
    r'(https?://[^\s]+)',
    caseSensitive: false,
  );

  final GlobalKey _richTextKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
      onLongPressStart: (details) {
        if (_isLongPressOnLink(details.localPosition)) {
          return;
        }
        widget.longPress?.call(widget.text);
      },
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12, horizontal: 8),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
        ),
        child: RichText(
          text: _buildRichTextWithLinks(widget.text),
          key: _richTextKey,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  TextSpan _buildRichTextWithLinks(String text) {
    final matches = urlPattern.allMatches(text);
    final textSpans = <TextSpan>[];
    int lastMatchEnd = 0;

    for (final match in matches) {
      if (lastMatchEnd < match.start) {
        textSpans.add(TextSpan(
          text: text.substring(lastMatchEnd, match.start),
          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.black),
        ));
      }

      final url = match.group(0)!;
      textSpans.add(TextSpan(
        text: url,
        style: const TextStyle(
          fontSize: 14,
          color: GlobalUI.hyperLinkColor
        ),
        recognizer: _LinkGestureRecognizer(
          url: url,
          onTap: () async {
            final uri = Uri.parse(url);
            if (await canLaunchUrl(uri)) {
              WebViewPage.show(url);
            }
          },
          onLongPress: () {
            widget.longPressLink?.call(url);
          },
        ),
      ));

      lastMatchEnd = match.end;
    }

    if (lastMatchEnd < text.length) {
      textSpans.add(TextSpan(
        text: text.substring(lastMatchEnd),
        style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.black),
      ));
    }

    return TextSpan(children: textSpans);
  }

  bool _isLongPressOnLink(Offset position) {
    final renderObject = _richTextKey.currentContext?.findRenderObject() as RenderParagraph?;
    if (renderObject == null) return false;

    final textOffset = renderObject.getPositionForOffset(position);
    final textSpan = renderObject.text.getSpanForPosition(textOffset);

    return textSpan is TextSpan && textSpan.recognizer is _LinkGestureRecognizer;
  }

}

class _LinkGestureRecognizer extends TapGestureRecognizer {
  final String url;
  final VoidCallback? onLongPress;

  _LinkGestureRecognizer({
    required this.url,
    GestureTapCallback? onTap,
    this.onLongPress,
  }) {
    this.onTap = onTap;
  }

  @override
  void resolve(GestureDisposition disposition) {
    if (disposition == GestureDisposition.accepted && onLongPress != null) {
      onLongPress!();
    }
    super.resolve(disposition);
  }
}



The issue is in the usage of the TapGestureRecognizer. This extension does not handle onLongPress events for you, you need to coordinate the gestures yourself.
Personally, I would move away from this implementation in favor of using an additional GestureDetector parent to your RichText widget.
I utilize stack here so that you don't have a GestureDetector as a parent to another GestureDetector but the parent/child structure that you have also works.
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return GestureDetector(
    behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
    onLongPressStart: (details) {
      if (_isLongPressOnLink(details.localPosition)) {
        return;
      }
      widget.longPress?.call(widget.text);
    },
    child: Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12, horizontal: 8),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
      ),
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () async {
        final uri = Uri.parse(url);
          if (await canLaunchUrl(uri)) {
            WebViewPage.show(url);
          }
        },
        onLongPress: () {
        widget.longPressLink?.call(url);
          },
        child: RichText(
          text: _buildRichTextWithLinks(widget.text),
          key: _richTextKey,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}


If you must utilize the TapGestureRecognizer I can update my answer with a LinkGestureRecognizer class rework that allows for the distinction between the two regions, however, does not accept multiple taps of the same link.

Thanks for your help. I notice that you text container now has a fixed size. I don't think in the IM scenario people will design their product like this. The container should grow and shrink according to the text. Maybe I could try two overlapping RichTexts.

The fixed size was only implemented for ease of reproducing your code on my end without your full application. If you replace what I have with what you have and simply adjust the RichText widget your desired result should be achieved. I will work on updating my answer.

Hi, I also noticed that your answer doesn't solve my problem exactly. I need the RichText to be PARTIALLY long-pressable, not the entire RichText to be long-pressable. That's the reason why I introduced _LinkGestureRecognizer. Like users can long press the link inside of a long text to bring out a context menu related to the link.

Very well I will update my answer if I have time tomorrow, but the same idea applies, wrap the widget you want to be long-pressable with the GestureDectector and the functionality you're looking for should be achieved.
